# List Value Comparison - For loop iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, vector, multiplication

I would like to compare item values. If they are equal, I want to print "true", otherwise I want to print "false". My code writes the results.

My result `"prediction_list"` in which I compare the values of 2 `lists(test_labels and my_labels`) should have a size of 260 because my original `lists(test_labels and my_labels)` have the size of 260. However, my `prediction_list` have the size of 67600 because of the for loop iteration. How should I correct it?

```
prediction = []

for i in test_labels:
    for item in my_labels:
        if item == int(i):
            prediction.append("true")
        else:
            prediction.append("false")

print prediction
```

Sample inputs and output:

NB Classifier labels in test set: `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

test_labels: `['0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n', '0\n']`

prediction: `['false', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'true', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false'...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @MarkPython, but there's a slightly cleaner syntax.

```
prediction = []

for i in range(len(test_labels)):
    if test_labels[i] == my_labels[i]:
        prediction.append("true")
    else:
        prediction.append("false")
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplification!

Comment: You're welcome! Python's range by default begins at zero unless defined otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looping through the lists try looping through a range and using the number to check the value of each item in each list at that index. Here is the code:

```
prediction = []

for i in range(0, len(test_labels)):
    if my_labels[i] == test_labels[i]:
        prediction.append("true")
    else:
        prediction.append("false")

print prediction
```

Comment: @serenade: You could also use list comprehension:  `prediction = ["true" if my_labels[i] == test_labels[i] else "false" for i in range(len(test_labels))`

Comment: I realize that you could do that but I prefer the long version for readability.

Answer (score 3):

If you sure test_labels and my_labels are same size, you can easily use "zip" function:

```
prediction = []

for x, y in zip(test_labels, my_labels):
    if x == y:
        prediction.append("true")
    else:
        prediction.append("false")

print(prediction)
```